# HP dv6000 Nvidia 7400 external monitor

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, hp, external-monitor

External monitor is working during upstart, when login screen appears, the external monitor goes black. The screen settings menu does not detect the external monitor. The Nvidia binary graphics device driver does not detect it either.

I have been forced to watch Doctor Who on a tiny laptop monitor, in absence of sonic screwdriver, please help! :D

nvidia fault message below:

> Unable to load X Server Display Configuration page:
>
> Failed to query NoScanout for screen 0.

Answer (score 1):

It not a perfect solution, but I inactivated the nvidia-173 driver that was installed from the beginning and are now using the nouveau driver, The external display works like a charm, but I have to go with the 2d desktop.

UPDATED NOW UBUNTU 12.4 WORKS WITH 3D!

Ubuntu 12.4 Alpha (Precise Pangolin), 29 February With latest updates. 3D mode is now avalible and external monitor works fine with the "Nvidia 295.20" driver.

Comment: Now you can install the latest drivers and remove the blacklisting.